# Probability and number of times of getting 13, 12, 11, and 10 correct picks out of 13 games in a soccer betting Jackpot

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

A soccer match contains 3 possible outcomes; Win , Draw or Lose. In a Jackpot of 13 games, if someone wants to try all possible picks,he will have to pick 3  raise to power 13=1,594,323 picks to guarantee that 1 pick will contain 13 correct outcomes.
But in this case the home teams can only win between 3 to 7 matches out of 13, Draw only occurs between 2 to 4 matches out of 13 and Away team wins between 3 to 7 matches out of 13. What is the total number of picks that will guarantee a pick of correct outcome of 13/13?

In the same number of picks, how many times will correct picks of 12, 11 and 10 occur?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If $I:=\left\{ \langle D,W,L\rangle\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}\mid D+W+L=13\right\} $
then: $$3^{13}=\sum_{\langle D,W,L\rangle\in I}\frac{13!}{D!W!L!}$$

However, for the answer you need a more complicated index set $I$.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer to the exact number of all possible outcomes for 13 games that comprises of draws from two to four, away wins 3-7, home wins 3-7. In fact I have them all in my laptop all scaned and put to trials but between me and you we both know that this is way too important information to share with at 0$ fee. I know you must be woundering why i havnt won yet and its because i have not enough money to cover for every single outcome. But with vatual trials the gig works. Tell you what, you offer me an amount and a'll be willing to share this info

Comment: Please, take care of the English! it is difficult to understand what you wrote!